# pass lambda to function that accepts function with templated types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I'm attempting to make a template function that takes a function as a parameter and the parameter function has arguments for the template to deduce.

Example time:

Here is a function that accepts a fixed function type and works

```
void func_a(void(*func)(int)) {
    func(1);
}
int main() {
    auto f = [](int x) -> void { printf("%i\n", x); };
    func_a(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what I want to do, expanding on the first example (this won't compile)

```
template <typename... T>
void func_b(void(*func)(T...)) {
    func(1);
}
int main() {
    auto f = [](int x) -> void { printf("%i\n", x); };
    func_b(f);       // neither of
    func_b<int>(f); // these work
    return 0;
}
```

Ideally I'd like `func_b` to accept both a regular function and a lambda function like `func_a` does, but with template magics.

Comment: have you tried using std::function instead of a C-function pointer?

Comment: @Hayt like replacing `void(*func)(T...)` with `std::function<void(T...)>`? If so, yes (and it didn't work for me).

Comment: how about just using `template <typename Fun> void func_b(Fun&& f)`? Your sample makes no sense anyway: you take variadic arguments, but then call the function with one int as argument

Comment: @stijn I agree my example is a bit contrived, but in my actual program the parameters of the incoming function are very important.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? The compiler will reject any function if the argument types don't match and there's no implicit conversion. Is it the latter you want to avoid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, template deduction doesn't work well with implicit conversions. However, you can convert the lambda explicitly into a function pointer type. The shortest, but somewhat confusing way to do that is to apply unary + operator:

```
func_b(+f);
```

Or you could use the more intuitive, but also verbose and DRY-violating cast operation:

```
func_b(static_cast<void(*)(int)>(f));
```

---

But perhaps, you'll want to simply accept *any* callable type, instead of only function pointers:

```
template <class Fun>
void func_c(Fun&& func) {
    func(1);
}
```

This works fine with lambdas. No conversions involved.

```
func_c(f);
```

And it also works for capturing lambdas (that cannot be converted to function pointers), `std::function` and function objects such as those defined in `<functional>`.

Comment: You probably want a `static_cast` there -- the chances of an error slipping in are quite high.

Comment: @Quentin perhaps so. I implemented your suggestion. It's even more verbose, though.

Comment: I really like the `+` operator idea, but I'm having troubles with the compiler (MSVC 14.0) saying "more that one conversion function from..." when applying the `+` to the simple lambda in my post.

Comment: @MichaelMitchell hmm, works fine in [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21cc2418a725f61d). Could be a msvc bug.

Comment: Now that I see the + operator it reminds me of how follys scope guard does this. It is a bit complicated but you can checkout https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/ScopeGuard.h and there are some talks out there by andrei alexandrescu how this works. (this also works on MSVC 14)

Comment: I haven't been able to find any documentation on the `+` operator, do you know where I could look for it?

Comment: @Hayt that's pretty cool! Does this mean I should define my own `+` operators?

Comment: you need to create a "wrapper" class it seems (and "fire" at some point). Folly does this in the destructor. Not sure if you can manage it in the constructor or have to call a fire manually.

Comment: @Hayt I see your "*should* only be done" and raise "*can* only be done". Good point, a reader of the answer may not be aware of the rule. I added mention to the latter part to emphasize the advantage of the more generic approach.

Comment: @user2079303 yeah I deleted the comment. I am not sure if the static cast will throw an error or not and did not have time to check this right now.

Comment: @Hayt unary + results in "no such operator", static cast (and even c-style cast) results in invalid cast error with capturing lambda.

Comment: @user2079303 everywhere I look, it seems the `+` operator not working in this case is a bug with VC++ :(
I'll go find someone to bother about this.

Comment: The VC bug is [#1471738 on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1471738/unary-operator-ambiguous-on-non-capturing-lambda). It's due to a non-conforming extension: non-capturing lambdas implicitly convert to a function pointer with `__cdecl`, `__vectorcall`, `__stdcall`, or `__fastcall` [calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx), so application of unary `+` is ambiguous.

Comment: @Casey I found another bug report that says it's resolved, https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1805962
maybe MSVC requires that you cast to one of the calling conventions?
I also found https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/31/visual-c-2015-update-2-bug-fixes/ saying the bug was fixed in VS2015 Update 2.

Comment: @MichaelMitchell (Disclaimer: I am a Microsoft employee.) I haven't spoken with anyone in the compiler front end team about it, but the bug in our internal tracker that corresponds to Connect#1471738 is marked Active. Yes, it seems contradictory to me as well.

Answer (score 3):

here you have some options that work:

```
#include <functional>
template <typename T>
void func_b(T&& func) {
    func(1);
}

template <typename... T>
void func_c(std::function<void(T...)> func) {
    func(1);
}    

template <typename... T>
void func_d1(std::function<void(T...)> func) {
    func(1);
}   

template<typename... Params>
using fun = std::function<void(Params...)>;

template <typename T, typename... P>
void func_d(T& func) {
    func_d1(fun<P...>(func));
}

int main() {
    auto f = [](int x) { printf("%i\n", x); };
    func_b(f);
    func_b(std::function<void(int)>(f));

    func_c(std::function<void(int)>(f));

    func_d<decltype(f),int>(f);
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is: A lambda is **not** a function pointer or `std::function`-object.

`func_b` uses perfect forwarding so `T` will be the type of the lambda not a `std::function` object.

For `func_c`. You should not convert a lambda to a c-style function pointer. A `std::function` object is able to do this conversion but only explicitly (by design) so you need to explicitly convert them.

`func_d` (and `func_d1`) combine the other aspects. It forwards the lambda and makes a `std::function`-object explicitly out of it though it needs an additional template parameter.

Comment: A [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) _is_ a function object. A [function object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FunctionObject) and a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) are two different (but related) things.

Comment: well it satisfies the c++ `FunctionObject` requirements. But I meant a `std::function`-object here.